# custom navigation bar notworking in angular

Tags: angular

> I am using angular9,I create a Navigation bar and Navigation slide
>   bar.When  I run my template it show every thing of my dashboard but it
>   cannot show me navigation bar and navigation slide bar,I  inspect my
>   code and check my mistakes in console but there is nothing
>   display(error) I dont know how can i do it.In my point of view I check
>   all my code but  I am not sure Where I create mistakes
>
> nav.ts

```
import { INavData } from '@coreui/angular';

export const navItems: INavData[] = [
  {
    name: 'Login',
    url: '/login',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    badge: {
      variant: 'info',
      text: 'NEW'
    }
  },
   {
     title: true,
     name: 'Theme'
   },
   {
    name: 'Colors',
     url: '/theme/colors',
    icon: 'icon-drop'
   },
   {
    name: 'Typography',
     url: '/theme/typography',
     icon: 'icon-pencil'
   },
   {
     title: true,
     name: 'Components'
   },
   {
     name: 'Base',
     url: '/base',
     icon: 'icon-puzzle',
     children: [
       {
         name: 'Cards',
         url: '/base/cards',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Carousels',
         url: '/base/carousels',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Collapses',
         url: '/base/collapses',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Forms',
         url: '/base/forms',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
      {
         name: 'Navbars',
         url: '/base/navbars',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'

     },
       {
         name: 'Pagination',
         url: '/base/paginations',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Popovers',
         url: '/base/popovers',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Progress',
         url: '/base/progress',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Switches',
         url: '/base/switches',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Tables',
         url: '/base/tables',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Tabs',
         url: '/base/tabs',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       },
       {
         name: 'Tooltips',
         url: '/base/tooltips',
         icon: 'icon-puzzle'
       }
     ]
   },
  {
     name: 'Buttons',
     url: '/buttons',
     icon: 'icon-cursor',
     children: [
       {
         name: 'Buttons',
         url: '/buttons/buttons',
         icon: 'icon-cursor'
       },
       {
         name: 'Dropdowns',
         url: '/buttons/dropdowns',
         icon: 'icon-cursor'
      },
       {
         name: 'Brand Buttons',
         url: '/buttons/brand-buttons',
         icon: 'icon-cursor'
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: 'Charts',
     url: '/charts',
     icon: 'icon-pie-chart'
   },
   {
     name: 'Icons',
     url: '/icons',
     icon: 'icon-star',
     children: [
       {
         name: 'CoreUI Icons',
         url: '/icons/coreui-icons',
         icon: 'icon-star',
         badge: {
           variant: 'success',
           text: 'NEW'
         }
       },
       {
         name: 'Flags',
         url: '/icons/flags',
         icon: 'icon-star'
       },
       {
         name: 'Font Awesome',
         url: '/icons/font-awesome',
         icon: 'icon-star',
         badge: {
           variant: 'secondary',
           text: '4.7'
         }
       },
       {
         name: 'Simple Line Icons',
         url: '/icons/simple-line-icons',
         icon: 'icon-star'
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: 'Notifications',
     url: '/notifications',
     icon: 'icon-bell',
     children: [
       {
         name: 'Alerts',
         url: '/notifications/alerts',
         icon: 'icon-bell'
       },
       {
         name: 'Badges',
         url: '/notifications/badges',
         icon: 'icon-bell'
       },
       {
         name: 'Modals',
         url: '/notifications/modals',
         icon: 'icon-bell'
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: 'Widgets',
     url: '/widgets',
     icon: 'icon-calculator',
     badge: {
       variant: 'info',
       text: 'NEW'
     }
   },
   {
     divider: true
   },
  {
     title: true,
     name: 'Extras',
   },
  {
    name: 'Pages',
    url: '/pages',
    icon: 'icon-star',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Login',
        url: '/login',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Register',
        url: '/register',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Error 404',
        url: '/404',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      },
      {
        name: 'Error 500',
        url: '/500',
        icon: 'icon-star'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Disabled',
    url: '/dashboard',
    icon: 'icon-ban',
    badge: {
      variant: 'secondary',
      text: 'NEW'
    },
    attributes: { disabled: true },
  },
  {
    name: 'Download CoreUI',
    url: 'http://coreui.io/angular/',
    icon: 'icon-cloud-download',
    class: 'mt-auto',
    variant: 'success',
    attributes: { target: '_blank', rel: 'noopener' }
  },
  {
    name: 'Try CoreUI PRO',
    url: 'http://coreui.io/pro/angular/',
    icon: 'icon-layers',
    variant: 'danger',
    attributes: { target: '_blank', rel: 'noopener' }
  }
];
```

> app.route.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { P404Component } from './views/error/404.component';
import { P500Component } from './views/error/500.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: P404Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 404'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '500',
    component: P500Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 500'
    }
   },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Dashboard Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Register Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/base/base.module').then(m => m.BaseModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'buttons',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/buttons/buttons.module').then(m => m.ButtonsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'charts',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/chartjs/chartjs.module').then(m => m.ChartJSModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'icons',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/icons/icons.module').then(m => m.IconsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/notifications/notifications.module').then(m => m.NotificationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'theme',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/theme/theme.module').then(m => m.ThemeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'widgets',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/widgets/widgets.module').then(m => m.WidgetsModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component:P404Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { P404Component } from './views/error/404.component';
import { P500Component } from './views/error/500.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';

const APP_CONTAINERS = [
  DefaultLayoutComponent
];

import {
  AppAsideModule,
  AppBreadcrumbModule,
  AppHeaderModule,
  AppFooterModule,
  AppSidebarModule,
} from '@coreui/angular';

// Import routing module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';

// Import 3rd party components
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppAsideModule,
    AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
    AppFooterModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    AppSidebarModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_CONTAINERS,
    P404Component,
    P500Component,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css",
              "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ng",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these attached in the angular.json file?

```
   "styles": [
        "styles.css",
         "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css",
         "node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css",
         "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css"
    ]
```

also my main.scss like this, works for me

```
// 3rd party libraries
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui";
```

Comment: yes ,I add this my angular.json,you can check my angular.json. That i upload recently

Comment: provide a minimal stackblitz please.

Comment: what is minimal stackbitz,I donot how how it provide

Comment: every thing file tiil  run the template,,but when i add login code in login template it work fine but dont show my nav bar